# How to disable auto focus/keyboard popup when the screen loads in .net maui blazor?

Tags: android, blazor, .net-maui

I am looking to disable the popup of keyboard when the screen loads (I have a searchbox which is in focus on load) in a .net maui blazor android app.
So far I  have tried
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" in the AndroidManifest.xml
which did not work for me.

I see some people have suggested
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN)
but I am not sure where to place it in the code?
Is there a specific way of doing it in the .net maui blazor framework?

Comment: Why would you have an input take focus but hide the keyboard? That sounds very annoying for the user.

Comment: Hey, it's a barcode scanner. So the user would essentially just scan in input area provided.

Comment: Ok, that is a good reason :) - have you tried setting `inputmode='none'` on the input?

Comment: Hey, yes I did try that, it hides the keyboard does not let me scan either.